# variables are not stored from writing them

Tags: python

this code simulates a bank atm  the user-defined functions are correct for the most part, but the main program is where it starts to not working correctly, if i were to type B,D or W, it'd loop 0.0 and not what I input for "you current balance". and the name doesn't get stored into printMenu(n), in the ouput it just has a blank space. and if i were to do Name=printMenu(n) it print the name entered but also "none"

```
#april 8th, 2023
#bank atm

def printMenu(n):
print("*" * 40)
print("welcome",n,"to the bank")
print("W for the WITHDRAWAL, B for balance, D for deposit, Q for quit")
print("*" * 40)

def getTransaction():
retval = input("what would you like to do: ")
return retval

def formatCurrency(amt):
return "${:,.2f}".format(amt)

def withdraw(bal, amt):
return True
bal = bal + amt - 10
#main program
Name = input("name on your bank account: ")
Balance = float(input("you current balance: "))

Name = ""
Balance = 0.0
Amount = 0.0
Command = 0.0
Deposit = 0.0


printMenu(Name)
Command = getTransaction()

while Command != "Q":
if Command == "B":
Balance = Balance + Amount
print(Balance)
#balance
elif Command == "W":
Withdraw = withdrawl - Balance
print(Withdraw)
#withdraw
elif Command == "D":
Deposit = Deposit + Balance
print(Deposit)
#deposit

printMenu(Name)
Command = getTransaction()

print("thank you for your transactions.")
```

Comment: Your code snippets are broken (note the [lacking] indentation)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code in the question. [Edit] your question and copy / paste your code into the editor once again. Re-highlight the pasted code and press ctrl+k to re-format the code correctly.

Comment: Just looking at the code and guessing what should be indented where, there are a lot of problems with the code. Some not-assigned variable names, some rows return before they calculate the value, and the While-loop is an infinite-loop if it ever succeeds to execute. However there is a bigger problem with this question, and that is that it isn't focused enough in a specific problem. Please simplify the question, and post it as a [mre] so that we can focus at one problem at a time.

Comment: **ALL** of your clauses should be changing the `Balance`.  You aren't thinking about what your bank is supposed to be doing.